# How can I push my local LARAVEL project to github public repository

Tags: git, laravel, github

Hi I am trying to push my local LARAVEL project to github but it is showing following error message:

```
To github.com:srungavarapu/LearningLaravel.git
```

! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:srungavarapu/LearningLaravel.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, your local and remote branches are not sync, if you want your changes on the remote branch try using force push

```
git push <remote> <branch> -f
```

But if you want the changes in the remote, first you need to do `git pull`

Answer (score 0):

> Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind

Your current local/master is not updated with remote/master. So, you need to `Pull` first then `Push`.

```
$ git pull origin master
$ git push origin master
```